# Maximum update exceeded (useEffect + Redux Hooks)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I am using Redux hooks. I am tried to dispatch from useEffect, but get error "Maximum update exceeded"

```
const state = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => ({data: state}));

const dispatch = useDispatch();

React.useEffect(() => {
    if (state.data.topics.topics === null) dispatch({type: 'GET_TOPICS'});

    console.log(state.data.topics.topics)

}, [dispatch, state]);
```

Comment: That makes sense if `state.data.topics.topics` always `null`, please make a reproducible example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What does `dispatch({type: 'GET_TOPICS'});` do? If it gets something from api then I'm curious how you'd handle that in the reducer (you can't, reducer is not async) or what middleware you have. Maybe dispatch that action on button click and check in the redux devtools what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each action dispatched to Redux, `state` is recreated. I.e. look at example reducer below

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'ACTION1":
      return { ...state, prop: action.prop }
    //...
  }
}
```

When `dispatch({ type: 'ACTION1', prop: 'something' })` is called new state object is received. And on every call to `dispatch` new state object is received.

`useEffect` has `state` in it dependency array. `useEffect` compare dependencies [using Object.is](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update) to detect changes. So when after call to `dispatch` new state is got, `useEffect` is firing again and calls `dispatch`. This creates infinite loop.

To break the loop, you need to make `useSelector` more specific. Don't select full state, but only props you'll use.

```
const topics = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => state.topics.topics);

const dispatch = useDispatch();

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (topics === null) dispatch({type: 'GET_TOPICS'});
  console.log(topics)
}, [dispatch, topics]);
```